# How to construct an empty data.table with the colum names of an existing data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create an empty data.table in R with colum names from another existing data.table.
Somehow I could not find a solution for that.

I would like to do something like that:

```
require(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(fn = c("A","B","C"), x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,3,4), a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
dt2 <- data.table(names=colnames(dt1)) # Gives 6 rows instead of 6 cols
```

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: @Adamm maybe post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
dt2 <- setnames(data.table(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(dt1))), names(dt1))

Empty data.table (0 rows and 6 cols): fn,x,y,a,b,c
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also take your old `dt1`, clear it and keep as `dt2`

```
dt2 <- dt1[0,]
dt2
Empty data.table (0 rows and 6 cols): fn,x,y,a,b,c
```

It isn't precisely what did you want, but it always some solution.

Comment: This answer also takes the correct column data types from the original `data.table` so I would prefer this answer over the marked one

Comment: since `dt1` is a `data.table`, `,` is not required also. i.e. `dt1[0]` works as well